# CUDA: Isn't Mark Harris's parallel reduction sample just summing each thread block?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

Link to his slides:

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf

Here's his code for the first version of parallel reduction:

```
__global__ void reduce0(int *g_idata, int *g_odata) {
extern __shared__ int sdata[];

// each thread loads one element from global to shared mem
unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
sdata[tid] = g_idata[i];
__syncthreads();

// do reduction in shared mem
for(unsigned int s=1; s < blockDim.x; s *= 2) {
if (tid % (2*s) == 0) {
sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s];
}
__syncthreads();
}

// write result for this block to global mem
if (tid == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
}
```

which he later optimizes. How is this not just summing all of the ints for each thread block and placing the answer in another vector? Is that what it's meant to do? Isn't *g_odata a vector itself since it's placing the sum at each "blockIdx.x" point in the vector? How do you get the vector g_idata to sum to one single number?

Comment: Yes that is what it does, and you get the final reduction  by running the reduction kernel *twice*.

Answer (score 3):

> How is this not just summing all of the ints for each thread block and placing the answer in another vector?

It is doing exactly that.

> Is that what it's meant to do?

Yes.

> Isn't `g_odata` a vector itself since it's placing the sum at each "blockIdx.x" point in the vector?

Yes, it is the vector containing the block-level sums.

> How do you get the vector g_idata to sum to one single number?

Call the kernel twice.  Once on the original data set, and once on the vector output from the previous call (the block-level sums).  Note that this second step uses only a single block and requires that you can launch enough threads per block to cover the entire vector, one thread per sum from the previous step.  If you review the [cuda sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction) that is intended to accompany that presentation that you linked, you will find such a calling sequence, for example at lines 304 and 333 of `reduction.cpp`.  The second call to `reduce<T>` performs the reduction that sums the partial block sums, as indicated in the comment on line 324:

```
304:reduce<T>(n, numThreads, numBlocks, whichKernel, d_idata, d_odata);

    // check if kernel execution generated an error
    getLastCudaError("Kernel execution failed");

    if (cpuFinalReduction)
    {
        // sum partial sums from each block on CPU
        // copy result from device to host
        checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(h_odata, d_odata, numBlocks*sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

        for (int i=0; i<numBlocks; i++)
        {
            gpu_result += h_odata[i];
        }

        needReadBack = false;
    }
    else
    {
324:    // sum partial block sums on GPU
        int s=numBlocks;
        int kernel = whichKernel;

        while (s > cpuFinalThreshold)
        {
            int threads = 0, blocks = 0;
            getNumBlocksAndThreads(kernel, s, maxBlocks, maxThreads, blocks, threads);

333:        reduce<T>(s, threads, blocks, kernel, d_odata, d_odata);
```

note that the output `d_odata` from the first reduction at line 304 is passed as the **input** to the second reduction on line 333.

Also note that the necessity for, and this method of **kernel-decomposition** is covered in the [presentation you linked](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) on slides 3 - 5.